# Three.js changing material on obj with button click

Tags: three.js

I'd like to be able to switch from a MeshBasicMaterial to a MeshLambertMaterial for an obj by clicking a button, and can't seem to figure out how to do it. Is there way to do so without needing to have 2 separate .obj files? I'm trying to switch the material of an .obj model of denim jeans.

The code below allows me to change the texture on button click, but not change the material. Thanks!

```
//start jean_1

    blue_denim_tex = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('stuff/blue_jean.jpg');

    black_denim_tex = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('stuff/black_jean.jpg');

    blue_mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({

        map: blue_denim_tex,


    }); 


    black_mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({

        map: black_denim_tex


    });


    objLoader1 = new THREE.OBJLoader();

    objLoader1.setPath( 'stuff/' );
    objLoader1.load( 'jean_1.obj', function ( object ) {
    object.traverse(function(child) {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
        child.material = blue_mat;

    }
    });
    jean_1 = object;
    jean_1.position.y= -24;

    scene.add( jean_1 );

    }, onProgress, onError );


//buttons

info.innerHTML += '<input id=jean1 type="button" onclick="blue_mat.map =blue_denim_tex" value="color: blue"/>';
info.innerHTML += '<input id=jean2 type="button" onclick="blue_mat.map =black_denim_tex" value="color: black"/>';
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create two javascript functions then traverse the object for assign the new meterial:

```
function setBlueMaterial () {
    jean_1.traverse(function(child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
            child.material = blue_mat;
        }
        jean_1.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
        jean_1.needsUpdate=true;
    });
}

function setBlackMaterial () {
        jean_1.traverse(function(child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
                child.material = black_mat;
            }
            jean_1.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
            jean_1.needsUpdate=true;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, how might i trigger the material change with the button?

Comment: Simply you can put the buttons in your page body and set in onclick event the function call `onclick="setBlueMaterial()"`

Comment: hmmm, can't seem to get it to work, am I to add in the above code after I load my original .obj code, or do I insert prior to onProgress, onError ); ?

Comment: I have created a simple version of the script... [link](https://jsfiddle.net/davnec/cffk23k7/) 
The function can be above or after the obj load.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to create the example...makes sense, but I keep getting an error "setBlackMaterial not defined" upon clicking.

Comment: Crazy, check if in javascript option (right gear on the javascript frame) load type is "No wrap - in <body>". It works for me!